# How to display the MonthCalendar control on top of Panels?

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

How can I display the `MonthCalendar` on top similar to the `DateTimePicker`drop down? I have a
a custom control (`TextBox` and `Button`) that displays the `MonthCalendar` dynamically when clicked.

I was able to get it in front of the controls with the panel but not over the panel. Image below;

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (mc.Parent == null)
       {
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(mc);
            mc.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y + this.Height);
            mc.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            mc.Show();
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop-down calendar on a `DateTimePicker` is a floating window, as is the drop-down list on a `ComboBox`. The `MonthCalendar` is just a regular control so, just like any other control, it cannot be displayed outside the bounds of its parent. If you want it displayed over a form and outside the bounds of a `Panel` then you'd need to make its parent the form, rather than the `Panel`. If you want it to be displayed outside the bounds of the form too then you'd need to create a new, borderless form and make that the control's parent.

Here is a method you can use to move a child control from one parent to another without changing its absolute position on screen:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Moves a child control from its current parent to a new parent while maintaining the same absolute location.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="child">
/// The child control to move.
/// </param>
/// <param name="newParent">
/// The new parent to move the child control to.
/// </param>
private void ChangeParent(Control child, Control newParent)
{
    var screenLocation = child.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);

    child.Parent = null;
    child.Location = newParent.PointToClient(screenLocation);
    child.Parent = newParent;
}
```

In your case, you probably want to call that like so:

```cs
ChangeParent(mc, this);
```

You may need to call `BringToFront` on the child control afterwards, depending on your z-order.

Note that you can also just add the `MonthCalendar` to the form in the designer and then change its `Location` in the properties window to get it in the right place.

Comment: Great... then I believe I would have to add the `MonthCalender` to the Form rather than the custom control `Parent`. Now, I have to discover the exact location relative to the `Form` so I can display it just below the custom control. Do you know of a direct way or example to do this, please?